# How to stop a ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, executorservice

The program finishes after nine prints:

```
class BeeperControl {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beep() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("beep");
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                beeper, 1, 1, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                beeperHandle.cancel(true);
            }
        }, 1 * 9, SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeeperControl bc = new BeeperControl();
        bc.beep();
    }
}
```

How to stop a process (i.e. java process in eclipse for example) because it does not stop after a time limit in 9 seconds?

Comment: Well ... What do you mean by "it does not stop after a time limit in 9 seconds"? I just tested it, and the "beep"s stop after 9 seconds, as expected. The whole program does not stop, of course, because you didn't shutdown the thread pool. If - instead of cancelling the beeper - you simply shutdown the scheduler after 9 seconds, your program will also exit normally. Is that the behavior that you wanted?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue you have is that the scheduler keeps a live thread around after you have cancelled the beep task.

If there is a live non-daemon thread, the JVM stays alive.

The reason that it keeps this thread around is that you have told it to do so in this line:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler
        = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Note the documentation of `newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize)`:

> `corePoolSize` - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.

So, you have two possible ways to cause the JVM to terminate:

1. Pass `0` to `newScheduledThreadPool` instead of 1. The scheduler will not keep a live thread, and the JVM will terminate.
2. Shut down the scheduler. You are supposed to do so anyway to release its resources. So change the `run` in your anonymous `Runnable` to:

   ```
   public void run() {
       beeperHandle.cancel(true);
       scheduler.shutdown();
   }
   ```

(In fact, you don't need the `cancel` there - the `shutdown` will take effect as soon as the next "beep" is completed.)