# How to shut down a Java ScheduledExecutorService based on a condition?

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I came across a way of stopping a Java ScheduledExecutorService which runs a periodic background task, after a time limit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202701/how-to-stop-a-scheduledexecutorservice) forum discussion.

In my case, I need to stop the ScheduledExecutorService when a certain condition is true. For example, I want to stop printing out "beep {count}", once the count exceeds 5. I have used the previously highlighted example for this purpose.

```
public class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private int count;

    public void beep() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count = count + 1;
                System.out.println("beep " + count);

                if (count == 5) {
                    scheduler.shutdown();
                }
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                beeper, 1, 1, SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeeperControl bc = new BeeperControl();
        bc.beep();
    }
}
```

Here, I have checked if the count is equal to 5 and then has used `scheduler.shutdown()` method to shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService.

My question is whether this is a good practice for the given scenario (as the ScheduledExecutorService is shutdown by a running task) or is there a better alternative which can be used in such a scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Mutable state (`count` variable) in a Multithreaded Environment is not recommended as it may result in stale value in `count` variable as a Read-Increment-Write (`count = count + 1`) is taking place.

It is good if you use a `AtomicInteger` instead of a plain old `int` for `count` variable.

```
public class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void beep() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count.getAndIncrement();
                System.out.println("beep " + count);

                if (count.get() == 5) {
                    scheduler.shutdown();
                }
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                beeper, 1, 1, SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeeperControl bc = new BeeperControl();
        bc.beep();
    }
}
```

Shutting down the `ScheduledExecutorService` by a running task is fine as in many scenarios that is what happens.