# How to load AdMob Interstitial ad only one activity?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

Right now I am working on one app which is include Interstitial ad but I am facing one problem that is I want to show ad in only MainActivity after every 2 min and when I move on next activity it will be stop. for this implementation I do something like this,

```
prepareAd();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Log.i("hello", "world");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    prepareAd();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

public void  prepareAd(){
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

Comment: is the add is showing in other activities also??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MohdAsifAhmed  ya right now ad is showing in other activity but I don't want to show in other activity

Comment: @DhrutiMistry - what you are trying to achieve is possible theoretically but its disallowed implementation - refer to link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287. You should track user activity within activity and after 2 clicks load interstitial ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a global reference:

```
boolean isActivityIsVisible = true;
```

Then check this by overriding activity's life cycle:

```
@Override
  protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  isActivityIsVisible = false;
}

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  isActivityIsVisible = true;
}

@Override
  protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  isActivityIsVisible = false;
}
```

Check whether Activity is visible in interstitial ads call back, If visible show it.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        prepareAd();
    }
    public void onAdLoaded(){
        if (isActivityIsVisible) { mInterstitialAd.show(); }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: With the `onPause` is enough, you don't need to change it in the `onStop` too (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @DhrutiMistry can you please post your whole implmentation to understand the issue you are facing.

Comment: You welcome @DhrutiMistry . Please accept and upvote answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

[How to stop a ScheduledExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202701/how-to-stop-a-scheduledexecutorservice)

Just do this in your first activity's onPause method. Then start it again in onCreate()

Comment: when I shutdown ScheduleExecutorService it is help me for another activity but in same activity ad only comes once not every 2 minutes. how can I resolve this?

Comment: in your "same activity" onCreate method, you have to enable ScheduledExecutorService again